# Why do I get "Only a single instance of this application can run" ?

Tags: windows, flash-player

I have been trying to update my Adobe Flash Player for hours.

I've read the forum, downloaded the uninstaller, restarted on every attempt. Tried for Firefox and IE.

When I click on the downloaded icon, it disappears and this message comes up: "only one instance of this application can run".

Also checked Adobe and other various sites for a solution. I need my browsers, with Flash.

Can someone help?

Comment: what version of Windows?

Comment: this sounds unintuitive but I saw it reported on a forum. Try uninstalling Microsoft Silverlight then reboot then reinstall Flash.

Comment: Reboot, open your downloads folder in Windows Explorer (*without* starting a browser), double-click on the downloaded file.

Comment: Reboot.  You probably have a crashed instance of the installer "running."  You can also kill it through task manager but since you're asking the question I would suggest the reboot route.

Comment: Alternate route: in Firefox, install [Shumway](http://mozilla.github.io/shumway/) (may or may not be sufficient for the goal you try to accomplish, if there's some site you're trying to view)

Comment: Download the Adobe Flash removal tool, completely remove all Flash versions, reboot computer and try to reload the Adobe Flash Exploit Kit (aka FlashPlayer).

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the downloaded file.
2. Open a browser, redownload it.
3. Reboot into Safe Mode with Networking (F8 after BIOS), install newer version of Flash.
4. Reboot into normal Windows.

Probably excessive, but simpler than looking for the potential rogue processes.